# Lynda.com removeChild

Tags: javascript, html, removechild

I am trying to remove this section of HTML from lynda.com:

> ```
> <div class="course-banner-artist"> Illustration by John Hersey </div>
> ```

This is what I have tried previously, but it was to no avail:

```
var i = 0
var bannerArtist = document.getElementsByClassName('course-banner-artist');
for (i = 0; i < banner.length; i++){
    bannerArtist[i].parentNode.removeChild(bannerArtist[i]);
}
```

Comment: bannerArtist.length, not banner.length

Answer (score 0):

Your for-loop is messed up. You are referencing an undefined object.

Fixed it for you

```js
var parent = document.getElementById("parent")
var bannerArtist = document.getElementsByClassName('course-banner-artist');

for (i = 0; i < bannerArtist.length; i++) {
  parent.removeChild(bannerArtist[i]);
}

parent.removeChild(bannerArtist[0])
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="parent">
    <div class="course-banner-artist">Some content</div>
    <div class="course-banner-artist">Some content</div>
    <div class="course-banner-artist">Some content</div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are removing [0] twice and please add a `var` to the `for (var i...`)

Answer (score 0):

As Patrick Evans pointed out "bannerArtist.length, not banner.length" was the problem. Thanks everyone who helped.